# Backpack for Laravel: Helper functions for Div widget

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

I find the Div widget in Backpack very awkward to write — it's arrays within arrays within an array. I needed some helper functions to make constructing a Div widget easier.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I came up with:

```
function cardWidget ($header, $body) { 
    return [ 'type'=>'card', 'content'=>cardContent($header, $body) ] ; 
    }

function cardContent ($header, $body) { 
    return [ 'header'=>$header, 'body'=>$body ] ; 
    }
```

As you can see from the examples that follow, creating a Div widget containing multiple Card widgets now just entails a single array of function calls. A lot fewer `[ ]` to keep track of!

And as a bonus, creating a single card is also a bit easier, as you can see in Row 2 in the examples.

```
    // Row 1: Three cards side-by-side
    Widget::add()  
        -> to('before_content')
        -> type('div')
        -> class('row')
        -> content( [   // array of widgets 
            cardWidget( 
                '<strong>Reports</strong>',                      // header
                '<a href="/LookupReport">Lookup Report</a>'      // body
                ) , 
            cardWidget( 
                '<strong>Donations This Year-to-Date</strong>',  // header
                '$' . number_format($ThisYTD, 2)                 // body
                ) , 
            cardWidget( 
                '<strong>Donations Last Year-to-Date</strong>',  // header
                '$' . number_format($LastYTD, 2)                 // body
                ) , 
            ] )
        ;  // end Row 1

    // Row 2: A single card
    Widget::add()  
        -> to('before_content')
        -> type('card')
        -> content( 
            cardContent(
                '<b>This is the heading</b>', 
                '<i>Need some content here.</i>'
                ) 
            )
        ;  // end Row 2
```

I welcome your suggestions, improvements, corrections, etc.```

Comment: Huh. This is pretty nifty. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: Feel free to incorporate the idea into a future release of Backpack. Someday I'll learn how to do PR via GitHub, but not today ...